# open and delete stored string from SQL database based on what is selected in listbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, listbox

I have a very basic program I'm writing to get used to using visual studio. The main window of the program contains a listbox named listBox1, and a rich text box named richTextBox1, as well as several buttons which perform various actions to get data from the table named `DocStorage`, which has a column named `DocumentName` that stores any words from richTextBox1 as a new row in the database.

I have managed to get the save feature to work, it takes any text from the richTextBox1 and stores in the database as a row, no problem.

Now I need to code for the `DELETE` and `OPEN` buttons. The `DELETE` button should remove a record from the SQL Server database, which is simple enough, but I can't figure out how to make it based on which item is selected from the listBox1 before the user pushes the `DELETE` button named `BtnDelete`.

I also would like to be able to work in reverse and `OPEN` that stored string back to the richTextBox1 based on which item the user has selected in listBox1 before they push the `OPEN` button named `BtnOpen`.

Trying to implement similar examples from the web has proven unsuccessful after many attempts, would appreciate some guidance in the right direction, so I can learn where I'm going wrong with coding these buttons.

I'm a beginner, so please forgive my ignorance and help me get these final two buttons of my first app completed!

Here is a snippet of my code for `BtnDelete_Click`

```
if (MessageBow.Show("Are you sure you want to Delete this File?", "Open File", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"...........");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE [DocumentName] from DocStorage where DocumentName=@DocShred", con);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocShred", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    con.Close();

    MessageBox.Show("Delete Successful", "File Deleted", MessageBoxButtons.Ok);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also your Delete query is not correct. It should be `DELETE FROM DocStorage WHERE DocumentName = @DocShred`

Comment: Thankyou Richa, I have corrected the query thanks to your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track - just not quite there yet....

Several things:

- first, you open the `con.Open()` and in the next line you create it again - from scratch - that doesn't make any sense.....
- you're never **executing** the query - you're building it up, adding parameter value and all - but you're never actually **running** the code!
- You should use `using(....) { .... }` blocks to ensure proper disposal of your resources

Try this code:

```
if (MessageBow.Show("Are you sure you want to Delete this File?", "Open File", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // define connection string (load from config) and query statement
    string connStr = ".......";
    string qryDelete = "DELETE [DocumentName] FROM DocStorage WHERE DocumentName = @DocShred";

    // set up the connection and command 
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qryDelete, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocShred", listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());

        // open connection, execute query, close connection
        con.Open();
        int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Delete Successful", "File Deleted", MessageBoxButtons.Ok);
}
```

Comment: Hi Marc, thank you for the very helpful reply.

I have run your code and it runs without error but for some reason is not actually removing the row from the database, although it is giving a Delete successful message, meaning the code ran through just fine. 

I'm double checking if I have made an error in entering your code or not, but I appreciate the helpful tip none the less, it should hopefully put me on the right track!

Comment: @lostintranslation: what does your connection string look like? Does it contain `AttachDbFileName=` ?? That would be a known issue....

Answer (score 0):

I ran this slightly modified version...

```
private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string TrashedDoc = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to Delete this File?", "Delete File", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {

                string connStr = @"...............";
                string qryDelete = "DELETE FROM [DocStorage] WHERE DocumentName = @DocShred";

                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qryDelete, con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DocShred", TrashedDoc));

                    con.Open();
                    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }

                /// if the Delete is successful a message box confirms to user

                MessageBox.Show("Delete Successful", "File Deleted", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            }

        }
```

and although the codes runs fine, for some reason it is not actually deleting the selected item in the listbox from the database, it just gives a Delete Successful message. Refreshing database confirms that it did not delete anything.